# Access Flickable from parent element

Tags: qml, qtquick2, flickable

I'm trying to call a function which is defined inside a Flickable element, but it seems impossible to access it by id. The following code produces `ReferenceError: flickable is not defined` when `tab.getValues()` is called:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Tab {
    id: tab
    function getValues() {
        flickable.getValues()
    }
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        clip: true
        flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
        contentHeight: column.height
        topMargin: 2 * pxPermm
        function getValues() {
            console.log("flickable.getValues() called")
        }
        Column {
            id: column
            // some content
        }
    }
}
```

How else am I supposed to access the Flickable element? The function getValues() must be placed inside the Flickable because it needs to access elements placed inside the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem with [`Tab`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tab.html) object. It's a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) whose default property is [`sourceComponent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#sourceComponent-prop). When you put a `Flickable` element inside it, it is [converted*](http://#) to Component and assigned. When your `Tab` object is viewed, it creates your `Flickable` object, which can be accessed via [`item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) property:

```js
function getValues() {
  if(tab.active)
    tab.item.getValues();
  else
    console.log("Tab is not viewed so item does not exists.");
}
```

That `Flickable` object have inherited, but different context than your `Tab` object. That means you can access `tab` from `flickable`, but not `flickable` from `tab`.